# Find first event and report year

Tags: r, search, time, row

Ciao,
I did post a similar inquiry but what I needed changed so deeply sorry as I work for a school district and they need different information!

Here is my replicating example.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b=c(1,0,NA,NA,0,NA)
c=c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010)
d=c(1,1,0,1,0,NA)
e=c(2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
f=c(1,0,0,0,0,NA)
g=c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014)
h=c(1,1,0,1,0,NA)
i=c(2010,2012,2014,2012,2014,2014)
mydata = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
names(mydata) = c("id","test1","year1","test2","year2","test3","year3","anytest","year")
```

The nuts and bolts is to find the first '1' in test1 and test2 and test3 and then add to column value in year1 or year2 or year3 based on where the first '1' is found. I am aiming to search through each row and find the first test column that is equal to 1. The new column I am aiming to create is "anytest." This column is 1 if test1 or test2 or test3 equals to 1. If none of them do then it equals to 0. This ignores NA values..if test1 and test2 are NA but test3 equals to 0 then anytest equals to 0. Now I have made progress I think using this code:

```
anytestTRY = if(rowSums(mydata[,c(test1,test2,test3)] == 1, na.rm=TRUE) > 0],1,0)
```

But now I am at a crossroads because I am aiming to search through each row to find the first column of test1 test2 or test3 that equals to 1 and then report the year for that test. So if test1 equals to 0 and test2 equals to NA and test3 equals to 1 I want the column which I created called year3 to be in date. Then last of all if test 1 and test2 and test3 all equals to 0 or NA or some combination of the sort then date should be last year which here is 2014.

Comment: @snoram I think OP want's to create the `anytest` and `year` columns.

Comment: anytest and year is expected output @snoram thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` from `base R` to create the `anytest` column

```
i1 <- grep('test', names(mydata))
NA^(rowSums(is.na(mydata[i1])) == 3) * (rowSums(mydata[i1] == 1, na.rm = TRUE) !=0)
#[1]  1  1  0  1  0 NA
```

If we also need a column of 'date', use `max.col` to get the column index of the max value of 'test' per row, extract the 'year' based on `cbind`ing the `row` index with column index

```
i2 <- grep('year', names(mydata))
m1 <- replace(mydata[i1],  is.na(mydata[i1]), 0)
i3 <- !rowSums(m1 == 1)
date <- rep(NA, nrow(mydata))
date[!i3] <- mydata[i2][!i3,][cbind(seq_len(sum(!i3)), max.col(m1[!i3,], 'first'))]
date[i3] <- do.call(pmax, mydata[i2][i3,])
date
#[1] 2010 2012 2014 2012 2014 2014
```

Comment: THis gives error `> date[!i3] <- mydata[i2][!i3,][cbind(seq_len(sum(!i3)), max.col(m1[!i3,], 'first'))]
Error in date[!i3] <- mydata[i2][!i3, ][cbind(seq_len(sum(!i3)), max.col(m1[!i3,  : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: @bvowe Initially, I forgot to paste one line.  Check now

Comment: OK, excellent. Lastly for `ID==6` `anytest` should equal to `NA` but instead I get value of `0` However I see in your output response you have `NA`. `NA^(rowSums(is.na(mydata[i1])) == 3) * (rowSums(mydata[i1] == 1, na.rm = TRUE) !=0)
[1] 1 1 0 1 0 0`@akrun

Comment: @bvowe  In my output the last one is `NA`.  Please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b=c(1,0,NA,NA,0,NA)
c=c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010)
d=c(1,1,0,1,0,NA)
e=c(2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
f=c(1,0,0,0,0,NA)
g=c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014)
h=c(1,1,0,1,0,NA)
i=c(2010,2012,2014,2012,2014,2014)
mydata = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
names(mydata) = c("id","test1","year1","test2","year2","test3","year3")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

mydata %>%
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.))) %>%  # update columns to numeric
  group_by(id) %>%                              # for each id
  nest() %>%                                    # nest data
  mutate(date = map(data, ~case_when(.$test1==1 ~ .$year1,      # get year based on first test that is 1
                                     .$test2==1 ~ .$year2,
                                     .$test3==1 ~ .$year3,
                                     TRUE ~ max(c(mydata$year1, mydata$year2, mydata$year3)))),  # if no test is 1 get the maximum year in the original dataset
         anytest = map(data, ~as.numeric(case_when(sum(c(.$test1, .$test2, .$test3)==1, na.rm = T) > 0 ~ "1",  # create anytest column
                                                   sum(is.na(c(.$test1, .$test2, .$test3))) == 3 ~ "NA",
                                                   TRUE ~ "0")))) %>%
  unnest()
```

which returns:

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 9
#      id  date anytest test1 year1 test2 year2 test3 year3
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  2010       1     1  2010     1  2012     1  2014
# 2     2  2012       1     0  2010     1  2012     0  2014
# 3     3  2014       0    NA  2010     0  2012     0  2014
# 4     4  2012       1    NA  2010     1  2012     0  2014
# 5     5  2014       0     0  2010     0  2012     0  2014
# 6     6  2014      NA    NA  2010    NA  2012    NA  2014
```

Comment: Yes, there should be a way, but the complexity in the code comes from the format of your data. It would be much easier if you had a tidier format, like `test1`, `test2`, ... as a column with the corresponding values in another column. An the same for `year1`, `year2`, ...

Comment: Do you mean like if i have: `a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b=c(1,0,NA,NA,0,NA)
c=c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010)
d=c(1,1,0,1,0,NA)
e=c(2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
f=c(1,0,0,0,0,NA)
g=c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014)
h=c(1,1,0,1,0,NA)
i=c(2010,2012,2014,2012,2014,2014)
mydata = data.frame(a,b,d,f,c,e,g,h,i)
names(mydata) = c("id","test1","test2","test3,"year1","year2","year3","anytest","year")`

Comment: I mean something like this `df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2),
                test_type = c("test1","test2","test1","test2"),
                test_value = c(1,1,1,0),
                test_year = c(2010,2012,2012,2014))` to start with. Each column has it's own meaning. Each `id` has a number of rows equal to the number of tests.

Comment: THis is great clarification. If I do this with the large school data what would be the code to then create the anytest and date metrics @AntoniosK very helpful

Comment: Have a look at this for more info: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html Usually a tidy format of data makes your data manipulation life easier and the code more clear.

Comment: very helpful thank you. So i decided to put my data in the tall format but haven't been able to determine how to get one new column for the first occurrence of the "1" do you have any further advice?